# Problem with dual monitors not presenting the proper resolution

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, dvi

i just came from Windows 10 to ubuntu 16.04 and can't find solution or any fix for my problem.
I'm using dual monitors (both the same models-Samsung S22D300N).Monitor(1) is connected via VGA-VGA cable, Monitor(2) is connected by VGA-VGA-to-DVI adapter.

On monitor(2) my ressolution can't pass 1360x768 while monitor(1) is running on 1920x1080.Everything is working okay on Win10, both monitors on 1920x1080.

I have installed lastest nvidia drivers but resolution problems is still there.
I'll do my best do provide all the necessery information.

GPU-Geforce GTS450

```
xrandr 

> Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3280 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 connected 1360x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00 +
   1360x768      59.96*   59.80  
   1152x864      60.00  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   680x384       59.96    59.80  
   640x480       59.94  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       72.19  
   320x240       60.05  
VGA-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1600x900_60.00 (0x3b6) 118.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1696 end 1856 total 2112 skew    0 clock  55.99KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  934           clock  59.95Hz
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x3b8)  9.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1976 end 2160 total 2400 skew    0 clock   3.85KHz
        v: height   60 start   63 end   73 total   76           clock  50.71Hz<
```

Comment: try using nvidia x server settings

Comment: I tried, it didn't let me use anything past 1360x768.

Answer (score 1):

First save any work in case your screen turns off and won't turn on without restarting.  What I am going to suggest is temporary to begin with; you can make it permanent if it works.

Go to the terminal and run `cvt 1920 1080 60`.

This will output a string of text or two.  The last one should start with the word Modeline.  Copy from the first text after Modeline which should be `"1920x1080_60.00" [...]` to the end of the line (should end with `[...] +vsync`.

Then type in `xrandr --newmode`  and paste what you copied.

Then type in `xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1 "1920x1080_60.00"`

Then type in `xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"`.

**To make it permanent:**

If this works, create or edit the file `~/.xprofile` and add the last three commands that you typed in into it.

Comment: "xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 "1920x1080_60.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  31
  Current serial number in output stream:  32
"

Answer (score 0):

Problem ocurred after update: 1920x1080 was not offered. Just unplugged and replugged the second screen.